# How to get validations working with simple_form on an ActiveRecord Store column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization, simple-form

In my model I have the following setup. It is correctly validating these attributes however the validations do not show up when using simple_form.

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :system_settings, accessors: [:attr_1, :attr_2, :attr_3], coder: HashWithIndifferentAccess

  validates :attr_1, presence: true
  validates :attr_2, presence: true
  validates :attr_3, presence: true
end
```

And my form is setup like this

```
= simple_form_for @node, html: {class: 'form-horizontal system-settings-form', multipart: true}, remote: true do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  = f.simple_fields_for :system_settings do |s|
    = s.input :attr_1, input_html: {value: f.object.system_settings[:attr_1]}
    = s.input :attr_2, input_html: {value: f.object.system_settings[:attr_2]}
    = s.input :attr_3, input_html: {value: f.object.system_settings[:attr_3]}
```

I am probably not using the form correctly because I am having to force the values instead of simple_form doing its magic (I wouldn't to have mind a better way of doing this). Can someone please help me setup this form to receive the validation errors for these fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line within your form at the top that posts them:

```
<% if @node.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
     <%= s.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %> 
      <li> <%= msg %></li>
     <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

You can either list all errors or just the first one etc.  The errors are an array so you can iterate through as desired.

Comment: Thats okay but I want to use simple_form for this. It can do much more powerful things than this.